# TFS - Customize releases view

Tags: tfs, customization

I'm using (on premise) Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 15.112.26307.0

I wanted to know if I can add a custom column to the releases view, so the approver can take a decision to approve from one environment to another based on that custom column.
I have two environments, first one runs automatically after a successful build, but the second environment waits for an approval. Since there will be a lot of approvals pending, I wanted to add a column with a custom value (I have that already) so the user doesn't need to go inside each release to search for the logs on each release searching for that value.

is that possible?

Also, is it possible to filter by user as in AzureDevOps version?

Thank you
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any built-in official task or extension could achieve your needs. You could first go through [Azure DevOps Service Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vsts) if there are some 3rd-party extension meet your requirement.

If you want to create an extension for TFS. Microsoft has created a GitHub repo with a number of samples and reading material to get you started. Otherwise, you may have to write your own extension, some tutorials for your reference:

- [VSTS Extensions Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples)
- [Develop Extensions for VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/)

As for how to accessing Azure Storage from a VSTS extension, take a look at this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2017/02/14/accessing-azure-storage-from-a-vsts-extension/).

For example, in your case, you could add **a summary section** contribution to Release summary page to display your custom value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that sounds in the direction I need. For example editing the existing summary widget on the dashboard to some custom values would solve the requirements. Thanks! I'll read those links/documentation